# Weird behavior of List type data in Dart language

Tags: flutter, dart

I found out some weird result which I cannot understand...

In case of int type, though newValue is changed, originalValue stayed same.
[image]

But it was not in List type
I expected originalList would be [1,2,3,4] but it changed as newList...

Anyone who can explain the reason??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newValue--` is really just a shortcut for writing `newValue = newValue - 1`, meaning that it will be assigned a new value. Meaning that after it `newValue` and `originalValue` point to different objects. In your second example `originalList` and `newList` point to the same list. Meaning that any changes made to it (by for example calling `removeRange`) will happen to both because the variable really points to the same object in memory. If you want that `newList` is a separate list that starts with the same values as `originalList` you can write

```
List newList = originalList.toList();
```